# Displaying quickbooks records to our rails application?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, rubygems, quickbooks

I am using quickeebooks gem in my rails 3.2 application. Here I am able to push customer information to the quickbooks successfully.

Now I want to display those records in my rails application for that I have written:

```
    oauth_client = OAuth::AccessToken.new($qb_oauth_consumer, current_login.access_token, current_login.access_secret)


    #creating customer in quickbooks
    customer_service = Quickeebooks::Online::Service::Customer.new
    customer_service.access_token = oauth_client
    customer_service.realm_id = current_login.realm_id
    customer_service.list

    @customer = customer_service.fetch_by_id(12)
```

and in view:

```
<%= @customer.name %>
```

This is working fine. But, I want to display all the customers that I have pushed in the quickbooks. So, I have written:

```
@customers = customer_service.list
```

In view :

```
<%= @customers.inspect %> is inspecting 3 records from quickbooks
```

But,

```
<% @customers.each do |customer| %>
 <%= customer.name %>
<% end %>
```

is generating

```
undefined method `each` for #<Quickeebooks::Collection:0xb5288d8>
```

How to solve this problem. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the "Bringing it all together" section on https://github.com/ruckus/quickeebooks, it appears to me that you'll need to write...

```
<% @customers.entries.each do |customer| %>
 <%= customer.name %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it, It was all my mistake. I was about to print array of objects.

But, Like steve have already suggested to use entries

```
<% @customers.entries.each do |customer| %>
  <%= customer.name %>
<% end %>
```

works for displaying all records

And in Controller :

```
filters = []
  filters << Quickeebooks::Online::Service::Filter.new(:text, :field => 'name', :value => "customer name" )
  customer = customer_service.list(filters)
  @customer = customer.entries.first
```

in views

```
<%= @customer.name %>
```

for displaying filtered records..